# Flight Simulator X transition from Missions to Free Flight

Tags: flight-simulator-x

In Flight Simulator X Steam Edition, I just flew the following missions successfully:

- Tutorial 1-5: Basic training
- Tutorial 8: Transition to Jet
- Rome-Naples Airline Run
- Caribbean Landing

I am just now trying to transition from the Tutorial Missions to scheduled airline runs. Should my experience be enough for transition to airline-style Free Flight, or should I do more missions (and which ones)?

Are there things I will have to observe, that go beyond the missions I flew?

I chose a 32.6 miles EDWB-EDDW low-level (3500ft) VFR via VOR WSR for a small test. I then found that the plane sits on the runway, and there is no radio traffic. Am I expected to initiate radio traffic and ask for takeoff clearance, and how can I enable a computer copilot that would handle radio traffic for me?

Answer (score -1):

1. press ` to go into the radio  panel ( you have to select the radio station)
2. there is no way you can get a copilot to do it for you unless your in mulitplayer

Comment: This only answer part of the question. You might wanna add to your answer so it covers the whole question.